# Conjugated linoleic acid (CLA) really helps in Weight loss or not?

Tags: weight-loss

I have been searching on web to figure out that CLA really helps in weight loss or not.

Some of the posts says its beneficial but some are contradictory suggesting that those are not helpful in any way to loose weight.

http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/david22.htm (supports)

http://www.webmd.com/diet/20040520/cla-weight-loss (supports)

http://blog.yourbestfatburner.com/how-can-cla-melt-your-fat/

http://www.shape.com/weight-loss/tips-plans/ask-diet-doctor-will-cla-help-you-lose-weight (suggest not useful)

https://www.ultimatenutrition.com/product/cla/

http://examine.com/supplements/Conjugated+Linoleic+Acid/

Any one having knowledge about, please suggest should I try these along my gym workout or not ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does! This has been proven by reserach.

"Long-term supplementation with CLA-FFA or CLA-triacylglycerol reduces BFM in healthy overweight adults." - http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15159244 (BMF means fat in your body.)

"CLA reduces body fat but not body weight in healthy exercising humans of normal body weight." - http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11725826

From examiner.com: "CLA is a supplement that has shown good results in rodents for weight loss however (like many bogus products) these studies have not been reliably replicated in humans." In my option, this is not true, as I shown in my previous answer. To take or not? Though question. Some reserach found it's safe and great, other found the opposite. I would try to obtain it naturally from grass-fed beef and Raw Grass-Fed Dairy, here I included some of the best sources of CLA:

Food Sources of CLA:

Food - Mgs. Of CLA/gm of total fat:

[30 - Grass-fed (G-f) Beef

20 - 30 - G-f Whole Milk

20-30 - G-f Cheese

5.8 - Lamb]1

Comment: You've got the substance of a good answer here but it's what's known as a link-only answer. If those links every go dead (and don't think they can't just because it's a government web site), your answer becomes worthless. Simply quoting the relevant conclusions from the studies along with the links would guarantee that your answer retains value no matter what the web site does.

Comment: That's a good idea, will do that next time. Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: You can do it this time. See the "edit" link  beneath your answer?

Comment: Done. Done. Done.

Comment: Thanks for Clearing my doubts but still in little confusion as examiner.com says its lackluster, what do you think it's worth trying or side effects are more weighted over benefits ?